# WiFi Hotspot + Simultaneous VPN connections

Tags: networking, vpn, wireless-access-point

I am trying to configure a setup on my Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop PC. So I have many iPod Touch's which can use WiFi to connect to a network. I want to host a WiFi Hotspot on my Ubuntu and connect my iPod Touch's to the computer running the WiFi Hotspot (preferably using DHCP reservations with MAC addresses). Then, I want that computer to connect to multiple VPN servers at the same time. Next, when I browse the Internet with that computer, I want it to use VPN #1. Finally, I want to specify to each iPod to specifically use VPN #X. Also, I want absolutely no traffic going to "internet" without using a VPN. I have already asked this question on other forums, and they suggested I use iptables, but i have 0 knowledge on how to do that. I think it would be easier to understand with an image, so I made a little schematic:

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCZLv.png)

So how would I do that?

For example purposes, I would use vpnbook since they offer free VPN service, but once I see it can be done, I would use NordVPN.

P.S. The whole point of this setup is to have a single computer managing the vpns of many iPods instead of having a single computer for each iPod (which would be a crap ton easier), and I want to use the PC's VPN because configuring the VPN on iOS 6.1.6 is not reliable since it reconnects every hour or so, thus showing my real IP for a brief moment.